# Generating a diff of two DOM elements (rather than two strings) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html-table, diff

This works really well for strings: http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

And I used to do string diffing server side (in ruby), but It's really hard to also take into consideration forced tag structure, like in tables.

What I did with just non table html was too add spans around the added and deleted text / inline elements. That method works well until you start trying to diff groups of TDs.

So, is there any Javascript library out there that will generate a visual diff with tables?

UPDATE / Example:

```html
Table1:                    Table 2:

<table>                     <table>
    <tr>                        <tr>
        <td>sometext</td>           <td>some <b>text</b></td>
        <td>moretext</td>           <td><b>more text</b></td>
    </tr>                       <tr>
</table>                    </table>
```

Resulting Table (just a possibility, as there are many ways to show diffs)

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some<del>text</del><add> <b>text</b></add></td>
        <td><del>more text</del><add><b>more text</b></add></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you question. Do you want to compare two DOM elements and find out whether and how their attributes, content etc differ? Or do you just want to compare the *text content* of two elements?

Comment: well, it would need to be recursive for tables. the attributes don't matter... but yeah, the text of the elements is what I need to compare. Unless there is a <strong> in a <td> then <strong> is included in the text comparison. =\ idk, I may just need to find a way to diff arrays in javascript, and use jquery to grab the elements grouped as arrays to pass them to said unwritten function.

Comment: So you want to compare the cells of two tables? I really think you should provide an example and the output you expect.

Comment: how about `if($('.cell1').text()==$('.cell2').text()) {...}`? or have I totally missed the question here.

Comment: I just added an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want to consider whether applied styles differ?  You say you want to compare the elements, but it looks like your output expects to be able to render the differences with simple `<add>` and `<del>` tags, which doesn't seem to work easily for non-html DOM properties.

Comment: yeah, if the attributes are different, then, the diff should catch it with add / del tags.

Comment: Just as an FYI, HTML has `<del>` and `<ins>` tags for similar purposes. I think you'll need to traverse the DOM, maybe using `$.grep` to simplify the code.

Comment: What should happen if the table structure is different? For example, if one table is 3x2 and the other is 2x3?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my initial attempt. It uses the diff library that you referenced and assumes that the tables are of the same dimensions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tbl1 tbody").children("tr").each(function(rownum, tr) {
        _tr = $("<tr>");
        tr2 = $($("#tbl2 tbody tr").get(rownum));
        $(tr).children("td").each(function(colnum, td) {
            text = $(td).html();
            text2 = $($(tr2).children("td").get(colnum)).html();
            _tr.append("<td>" + diffString(text, text2) + "</td>");
        });
        $("#results").append(_tr);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SPSJb/

Comment: tis a good example. But a fully capable script is going to be ridiculously ugly, I feel. =(

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented https://github.com/teamwork/visual-dom-diff which compares 2 DOM nodes and generates a `DocumentFragment` with all differences wrapped in `<ins>` and `<del>` elements as appropriate. It think it could be appropriate for your use case.